# Grails Domain transients and calculations

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have a grails domain that looks like the following

```
User {
  sortedSet notifications
  static hasMany=[notifications:Notification]
}

Notification {
  Date dateCreated
  int status=0
  static belongsTo=[user:User]

  @Override
  public int compareTo(obj) {
     dateCreated.compareTo(obj.dateCreated)
  }
}
```

If I return the "User" object to a GSP, is there any way to get the count of all notifications where status=1.

Eg:  user.notifications.size()  (but where status=1)

Without having to return another separate notifications object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention the word "transients" in the title, but nowhere else.  Are you wanting to declare a transient property to do something like this?...

```
class User {
    SortedSet notifications
    static hasMany=[notifications:Notification]
    static transients = ['numberOfStatusOnes']

    int getNumberOfStatusOnes() {
        notifications?.count { it.status == 1 } ?: 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `namedQueries` or alike:

```
class User {

  static hasMany=[notifications:Notification]

  static namedQueries = {
    notificationsByStatus{ int status = 1 ->
      notifications{
        eq 'status', status
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can call the query so

```
User.notificationsByStatus.count()
```

Comment: hi that's close... the 'notifications' comes up with an underline... eg it cant resolve this? and when i try launch the program and look for ${user.notificationsByStatus} it can't resolve this.."No such property: notificationsByStatus for class: tutor.com.User"

Comment: ${user.notificationsByStatus} shouldn't work at all. you must call `${user.notificationsByStatus.count()}` or `${user.notificationsByStatus.list()}`

Comment: which grails version are you using?

Comment: nah doesnt work... unless my grails version is old.. even when itry do  ${user.notificationsByStatus.count()} i get   by MissingPropertyException: No such property: notificationsByStatus for class: tutor.com.User

Comment: try `user.notificationsByStatus().count()`

Comment: No signature of method: tutor.com.User.notificationsByStatus() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: `User.notificationsByStatus().count()` of course sorry

Comment: woops ok it works with this ${User.getNotificationsByStatus().count() }  ... but it shows for ALL users.. just specific to this user .. so it shows the count for all of them where status=1

Comment: can i add somewhere.. to make sure user=this.user object in the namedqueries

Comment: you can simply call `Notifications.countByUserAndStatus( user, 1 )`

Comment: no luck...  I am inside a GSP, i've returned a User object... all i want is to get the  User's notification.count where status=0..

Comment: this is NOT possible for `Notifications.countByUserAndStatus( user, 1 )` to return a user object. btw, do you need status=0 or status=1?

Comment: status=0. Basically i just want an easy way for returning  user.notifications.count where status=0  (using the domain initially posted in this query)

Comment: The original question includes "If I return the "User" object to a GSP...".  Defining a named query like this doesn't seem consistent with that.

Answer (score 0):

> If I return the "User" object to a GSP, is there any way to get the
>   count of all notifications where status=1

Since you are returning the `User` to the GSP I assume there is some reason that you want that object and constructing a different query which only returns the status 1 notifications isn't what you want.  Instead, you can just interrogate the `User` and get the information you want.

In your controller which is retriving the user object you can do something like this:

```
def someAction() {
    User u = // you got your user from somewhere:
    int numberOfStatusOnes = u.notifications.count { it.status == 1 }

    [user: u, numberOfStatusOnes: numberOfStatusOnes]
}
```

Then in your GSP when you refer to `user` that will be an instance of the `User` class and when you refer to `numberOfStatusOnes` that will be a number that indicates how many `Notification`s that `User` has which have a `status` of 1.